# Create function to split on seperators

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

This function takes in two arguments, text and separators which are both strings and returns a list of non-empty, non-blank strings from text, determined by splitting text on any of the separators.
separators is a string of single-character separators.

Here is an example:

```
def split_on_separators(text, separators)
>>>split_on_separators("Hooray! Finally, we're done.", "!,")
['Hooray', ' Finally', " we're done."]
```

This is what I have so far:

```
    location_of_sep = []
    result = []
    for i in range(len(text)):
        if original[i] in separators:
            location_of_sep.append(i)
```

I'm stuck after this part. Now that I have the location of the separator, how can add it to the list result. 
I tried the following:

```
location_of_sep= [6, 15] #location of separator for the example given above
for j in location_of_sep:
    result.append(text[0:j])
```

This does not work because it does not get the text between the two separators. I may be over thinking this. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 4):

How about using [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split("[!,]", "Hooray! Finally, we're done.")
['Hooray', ' Finally', " we're done."]
```

---

If you don't want to use regular expression:

Using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip), you can make pairs.

```
>>> text = "Hooray! Finally, we're done."
>>> location_of_sep = [6, 15]

>>> zip([-1] + location_of_sep, location_of_sep + [None])
[(-1, 6), (6, 15), (15, None)]

>>> [(i+1,j) for i, j in zip([-1] + location_of_sep, location_of_sep + [None])]
[(0, 6), (7, 15), (16, None)]

>>> [text[i+1:j] for i, j in zip([-1] + location_of_sep, location_of_sep + [None])]
['Hooray', ' Finally', " we're done."]
```

Comment: +1 for recommending re.split and answering the question to boot